# Combine data points with multipolygons in R

Tags: r, geometry, polygon, datapoint

I have an Excel file containing over 3000 data points and a census shapefile including multipolygons of areas in the U.S. I would like to use R to create a column in the Excel file telling me in which area (polygon) each data point is located. So, I would like to combine both files through the data points and polygons.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

I looked for different solutions. However, since I am pretty new to R, I am not able to adapt the codes I found to my specific problem.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example to handle your problem using `dput()`.